# Angular Data Binding Between Components

Tags: angular, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to share data between the app component and another component in my project. I used the parent-child data binding using the `@input` decorator but when I do this

```html
<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
<app-customer-registration [client]="client"></app-customer-registration>
```

in the app component template, the child template(app-customer-registration) is rendered twice on the screen.

my routing config:
[image: Routing config]

Comment: Does your current route url also load this component?

Comment: Share yours routing configuration.

Comment: yes please, it does.

Comment: @ammadkh, i just added the routing config to the edit.

Comment: Of course it will, you're putting it on the html and then routing to it. You should use a shared subject/service to share data. https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

Comment: @eko alright, i will try that out